# Do unused variables get GC'd if not used within a closure?

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

Assuming the following code:

```
const someFunction = (someString, largeObject) => {
  console.log(largeObject.huge);

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(someString);
  }, 10000000000000);
};

someFunction('something', { huge: 'object', tons: 'of data' });
```

`someFunction` uses the `largeObject` and then creates an anonymous function to be called way in the future. The new function doesn't use the `largeObject` at all.

Does the `largeObject` get garbage collected after `someFunction` returns or does it stick around because the anonymous function has a closure over the scope?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can't reference the classInstance variable anymore, it wil be GC'd. Hence `largeObject` will be marked for GC